# Don't touch my curve

Tags: riddle, mathematics, knowledge

> What the heck is this? A zero, or not?
>
> Him after me, no more problem. Take the fourth and the fifth.
>
> You want some uniform? Take my test.
>
> But don't touch my curve. It's in one piece, but has spikes everywhere!

Who am I?

Answer (score 1):

I am confident you are

> Karl Weierstrass.

The last clue refers to the

> Weierstrass function, continuous everywhere, differntiable nowhere.

The third clue refers to

> Weierstrass M-test for uniform convergence.

Still working on exactly what the first and second reference, will update soon.

The first clue

> Possibly a reference to the Weierstrass factorization theorem which concerns the relationship between an entire complex function and it’s zeroes.

The second clue

> The second clue is almost surely referring to the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit, proved first by Bolzano and finally established in mainstream mathematical thought by Weierstrass. $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are the fifth and fourth letters of the Greek alphabet, so "him after me" refers to the swapping of the order of those two letters.

Comment: I think the second line might be about rot13(gur Trezna ynathntr).

Comment: Actually, "he" is rot13(Pnhpul).